# Is there a way to make asp.net Boundfield a link?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Im sorry if this has been asked before, but i have searched the forums for quite some time and have not been able to find a solution to my problem.

I am currently developing a web application where users are able to donate bottle deposit. When users have uploaded the bottles they will be shown in the following table:
[Snippet of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEERX.png)

The data is shown in a gridview with a SqlDataSource. The code:

```
<div class="table-responsive col-8">
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:WeCANConnectionString %>"
                    SelectCommand="SELECT [creator], [amount], [details], 
                    [imageurl], [pickup], [available_from] FROM [deposit] ORDER BY [id] DESC"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                <asp:GridView id="GridView1" class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="creator" HeaderText="Uploaded By" SortExpression="creator" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="amount" HeaderText="Amount" SortExpression="amount" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="details" HeaderText="Details" SortExpression="details" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="imageurl" HeaderText="Image" SortExpression="imageurl" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="pickup" HeaderText="Location of the bottles" SortExpression="pickup" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="available_from" HeaderText="Available from" SortExpression="available_from" />
                    </Columns>

                </asp:GridView>
```

I would like to be able to click on each individual post and create dynamic pages where more data from the database is shown. I read somewhere that i was possible to create these page with the ID of each post but i couldnt find anything that showed how it works.

Be free to ask any follow questions. This is my first post so im not sure if i have covered everything.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: My mistake. It has now been edited. Thank you

Comment: So you want to be able to click on a row, or like maybe a link in the row, that would open a new tab or window that has details about the associated record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is with a link in each row.  First, you need to add "id" to the `SELECT` in your DataSource, so the data is accessible at the time the table is bound.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:WeCANConnectionString %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT [id], [creator], [amount], [details], [imageurl], 
    [pickup], [available_from] FROM [deposit] ORDER BY [id] DESC">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Then in your GridView, make a template column with a HyperLink, and have the NavigateUrl of that HyperLink open a new page with the ID on the query string.  If you don't want the ID to be exposed in the URL, you may need to obfuscate it in some way, or use perhaps a GUID column in the DataBase for each record.  As long as you can identify it.  Your NavigateUrl can be whichever page you want, but in this example I used DetailPage.aspx.

```
<asp:GridView id="GridView1" class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="DetailsLink" runat="server" 
                    NavigateUrl="DetailPage.aspx?id=<%# Eval("id")%>"
                    Text="Details" Target="_blank">
                </asp:HyperLink>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="creator" HeaderText="Uploaded By" SortExpression="creator" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="amount" HeaderText="Amount" SortExpression="amount" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="details" HeaderText="Details" SortExpression="details" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="imageurl" HeaderText="Image" SortExpression="imageurl" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="pickup" HeaderText="Location of the bottles" SortExpression="pickup" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="available_from" HeaderText="Available from" SortExpression="available_from" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

The <@# Eval('id')@> will render the ID for each row as a query string in the URL.

Comment: This was exactly what i was looking for. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you well, You can use Template Field

```
  <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton Text="text" runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```